# How to avoid Circular type dependency with ConnectedProps in a dumb component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

We have a coding pattern that splits a react component into two files, say `smart.ts` and `dumb.ts`

`dumb.ts` is a normal react component accepting some props.
`smart.ts` will import selectors, actions and dumb component and export with connect HOC so props are injected - say `export connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dumb)`.

This helps that component in `dumb.ts` can be used in storybook, but in application its connected with redux and parent need not supply all props.

**Issue**

We can use `ConnectedProps` to get types of props passed to connect. That would be defined in `smart.ts` as connect is present there.
Now, to use that type for prop definition in `dumb.ts`, we need to import it from `smart.ts`, which causes a circular dependency (as smart already import dumb to wrap in connect).

Sample code (though codesandbox doesn't throw circular dependency error)
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-typescript-forked-gs00w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `ConnectedProps` from redux, this can be solved by importing Data / Action props from dumb component and passing into connect function as below.

```
const withConnect = connect<
  DataPropsFromComponent,
  ActionPropsFromComponent,
>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
```

This way, it is required to define prop in dumb component, but TS validates it against what is provided from connect function - if there is a mismatch it would be a type error.

Updated example to show this in action, alongside handling external props that can be injected from outside Smart component as well.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-typescript-forked-qu5vy

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just define ToggleDumbProps in ToggleDumb component and import both interface and the component in the Dumb file?

So in SmartComponent you can have SmartProps merged with DumbProps.

Comment: This would mean the props types need to be manually defined in dumb component right?  I.e if one of connected prop types change it won't automatically reflect?